# SQL While and if loop

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, sql-update

I'm trying to write a while loop in sql but it couldnt. I'm trying to look all rows and if students final score >60 ı want to update his score as passed.

```
while(select  Result from Student) IS NOT NULL
  begin
  IF ( select Final_Score from Student )> 60 
  begin
  update Student set Result='Passed'
  end
  else
  begin
  update Student set  Result='Failed' 
  end 
  end
```

I want to use While loop . How can I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

SQL is a *query* language and does not have any procedural elements (loops, conditionals).

A condition like the one you want is simply expressed with a WHERE clause:

```
update student
    set result = 'Passed'
where final_score > 60;

update student
    set result = 'Failed'
where final_score <= 60;
```

Alternatively you can use a CASE expression and run only one UPDATE statement

```
update student
    set result = case 
                   when final_score > 60 then 'Passed'
                   else 'Failed'
                 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as:

```
update Student set Result=CASE WHEN Final_Score > 60 THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END
```

Single set-based query will be much more performant than loop.

Comment: I got this error  
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

for while clause

Comment: @fd2812 There is no suqbquery in my example. This is single statement operation